# How to reset solr back to first use?

Tags: solr, lucene

I'm having a lot of problems running my solr server. When I have problems committing my csv files (its a 500 MB csv) it throws up some error and I am never able to fix it. Which is why I try to clean up entire indexing using

```
http://10.96.94.98:8983/solr/gettingstarted/update?stream.body=<delete><query>*:*</query></delete>&commit=true
```

But sometimes it just doesnt delete. In which casese, I use the

```
bin/solr stop -all
```

And then try, but again it gives me some errors for updating. Then I dedicided to extract the install tarball deleteing all my revious solr files. And successfully it works!

I was wondering if there is a shorter way to go about it. I'm sure the index files arn't the only that are generated. Is there any revert to fresh installion option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are calling the update command against the right collection and you are doing commit, you should see the content deleted/reset. If that is not happening, I would check that the server/collection you are querying is actually the same one you are executing your delete command against (here **gettingstarted**). If that does not work, you may have found a bug. But it is unlikely.

If you really want to delete the collection, you can unload it in the Admin UI's Core page and then delete from the disk. To see where the collection is, look at the core's Overview page on the right hand side. You will see **Instance** variable with path to your core's directory. It could be for example: **.../solr-6.1.0/example/techproducts/solr/techproducts** So, deleting that directory after unloading the core will get rid of everything there.

Comment: Thank you. Just what I need.